# Why does my component rerender at onChange and not onClick?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Im trying to figure out why does my component re-render only when I am typing on my textfield (Im guessing it changes because of the onChange part? ) where it does not re-render after I made the API call on my onClick button

The below is my code:

```
export default function HomePage() {
    const [searchBook, setSearchBook] = useState('');
    const [bookList, setBookList] = useState([]);
    
    return(

       <Box>

         <Box className='home-page-right-search-box' display='flex' flexDirection='row' alignItems='center' sx={{}}>
                <Box flex={3} sx={{ fontSize: '75px' }}>
                    Explore
                </Box>
                <Box className='home-page-right-search-textfield' flex={1} display='flex' flexDirection='row'>
                    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="   Search" variant="outlined" sx={{ boxShadow: '0px 0px 10px 2px #C0C0C0', width: '350px', mr: 2 }} onChange={(value) => {
                        setSearchBook(value.target.value)
                    }} />
                    <Button sx={{ color: '#364d8a' }} onClick={
                        async () => {
                            const response = await GoogleBookSearch(searchBook);
                            setBookList(response);
                        }}>
                        Search
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box className='home-page-right-trending-container' sx={{ mt: 10, px: 2 }}>
                <Box sx={{ mb: 5, fontSize: '35px' }}>
                    Trending
                </Box>
                <Grid container spacing={5}>




              ////*****This is the place where it is not re-rendering after onClick******///


                    {bookList.map((book) => {
                        console.log('book: ', book)
                        return (
                            <Grid item >
                                <Box className='home-page-right-trending-list-item' textAlign='center' sx={{ mt: 3, mr: 2 }} >
                                    <Box className='trending-list-item-img-box'>
                                        <img className='trending-list-item-img' src={book.imageLink} alt='book image' />
                                    </Box>
                                    <Box className='trending-list-item-title' sx={{ mt: 1, fontSize: '20px', color: 'grey', width:'200px' }}>
                                        {book.title}
                                    </Box>
                                    <Box sx={{ mt: 1, fontSize: '15px', color: 'grey' }}>
                                        {book.author}
                                    </Box>
                                    <Box sx={{ mt: 1, fontSize: '20px' }}>
                                        ⭐️ {book.rating}
                                    </Box>
                                </Box>
                            </Grid>
                        );
                    })}

                </Grid>
            </Box>
       </Box>
    );
}
```

This is my API call:

```
export async function GoogleBookSearch(name) {
const bookDetails = [];
try {
    await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${name}`).then((result) => {
        result.json().then((item) => {
            const itemsFirstTen = item['items'].slice(0, 10);
            
            for (var i in itemsFirstTen) {
                // console.log( 'sales info: ', itemsFirstTen[i]['saleInfo']);
                bookDetails.push({
                    title: itemsFirstTen[i]['volumeInfo']['title'],
                    subtitle: itemsFirstTen[i]['volumeInfo']['subtitle'],
                    authors: itemsFirstTen[i]['volumeInfo']['authors'],
                    description: itemsFirstTen[i]['volumeInfo']['description'],
                    price: itemsFirstTen[i]['saleInfo']['saleability'] === 'FREE' || 'NOT_FOR_SALE' ? 0 : itemsFirstTen[i]['saleInfo']['listPrice']['amount'],
                    imageLink: itemsFirstTen[i]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'],
                })
            }
        })

    });


    // return response;

} catch (error) {
    console.log('error searching book: ', error);
}
    console.log('bookdetails: ', bookDetails)
    return bookDetails;
}
```

The API calls return exactly what I want and I've reformated it to the way I want it as well.

I just want my component to re-render to the latest search result and re-renders after onClick; not when I start typing again in the textfield then it renders out what my last search result was.

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The code wasn't rerendering correctly because the `GoogleBookSearch` code wasn't correctly waiting to populate the `bookDetails` array. I suspect it's due to nesting the `result.json()` promise chain and not returning it. In other words, the `await fetch(....).then((result) => { ... })` Promise resolved and the rest of the `GoogleBookSearch` function ran and returned an empty `bookDetails` array ***before*** the nested `result.json()` Promise chain resolved and later mutated the `bookDetails` array.

This is why clicking the search button wasn't triggering a rerender, but then later when you again typed in the search input, it *would* trigger a rerender and you'd see the mutated `bookList` state.

```
export async function GoogleBookSearch(name) {
  const bookDetails = [];
  try {
    await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${name}`)
      .then((result) => {
        // (1) Nothing returned from here on, so the outer Promise resolved
        // (2) This start a new, nested Promise chain
        result.json()
          .then((item) => {
            const itemsFirstTen = item['items'].slice(0, 10);
            
            for (var i in itemsFirstTen) {
              // (4) bookDetails array mutated!!
              bookDetails.push({ ...book data... });
            }
        })

    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error searching book: ', error);
  }
  console.log('bookdetails: ', bookDetails);

  // (3) bookDetails array returned
  return bookDetails;
}
```

## Solution

Don't nest Promise chains, Promises were created to eliminate "nesting hell". You *could* return the nested Promise and keep the Promise chain flattened.

Don't mix `async/await` with Promise chains either though. Use a `try/catch` with the `async/await` code and keep the code looking "synchronous".

Example:

```
async function GoogleBookSearch(name) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${name}`
    );
    const result = await response.json();

    return (result.items || []).slice(0, 10).map((book) => ({
      title: book.volumeInfo.title,
      subtitle: book.volumeInfo.subtitle,
      authors: book.volumeInfo.authors,
      description: book.volumeInfo.description,
      price:
        book.saleInfo.saleability === "FREE" || "NOT_FOR_SALE"
          ? 0
          : book.saleInfo.listPrice.amount,
      imageLink: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error searching book: ", error);
  }
}
```

[image: Edit why-does-my-component-rerender-at-onchange-and-not-onclick]